# How to speed up Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, nvidia, windows-7

I have Windows 7 and Ubuntu 14.04 on my machine.

It's an average home configuration, and I use it for web development too.

- 4GB DDR2
- 300 GB HDD
- 2,2Ghz Dual core
- Nvidia 8600GT GPU

Ubuntu boots very fast, much faster than Windows... and uses much less RAM than Windows, but damn man, Ubuntu is laggy as hell, it is nowhere near as smooth as Windows.
Firefox is slow  as hell, it works but not nicely like on Windows. I know that Linux is made for servers, but UI is just awful. I don't want my Linux to look fancy like a brand new Mac, I just want it t run as smooth as Windows does. Any tips?

**Edit:** 
Here is my output from terminal when run `lspci -nnk | grep -A3 VGA`

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation G84 [GeForce 8600 GT] [10de:0402] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: CardExpert Technology Device [10b0:1401]
    Kernel driver in use: nouveau
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme BCM5754 Gigabit Ethernet PCI Express [14e4:167a] (rev 02)
```

Comment: No man, just no!

Comment: It usually helps to switch to a community flavour with a light desktop environment. The same Ubuntu engine is humming under the hood. See this link, https://askubuntu.com/questions/930118/ubuntu-12-04-lts-updates/930165#930165

Comment: I guess that avoiding problem is not solution... thanks anyway..

Comment: I think the problem is that the desktop environment 'Unity' of standard Ubuntu needs quite modern hardware for the graphics, and I don't know any better solution than to replace it with another desktop environment or replace the hardware (a new graphics card). Replacing the HDD with an SSD might speed things up too, but hardware costs money, and you can try the community flavours of Ubuntu for free.

Comment: Which graphics driver are you using? Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of the terminal command `lspci -nnk | grep -A3 VGA`? Thanks.

Comment: Hi David, I have edited my question.

Comment: You are using the free 'nouveau' graphics driver. Maybe it will work better with a proprietary nvidia driver according to this link, https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2242665&p=13114351#post13114351, it is worth trying. Good luck :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try to check running service.
You can use bum

```
sudo apt-get install bum

sudo bum
```

and look for un-needed service you can stop.